# iOS(Swift) How can I call my application when I get push notice?

Tags: ios, swift, apple-push-notifications

Language: Swift 3

I'm using APNS in order to run MFMessageComposeViewController.
I don't know how to run my application when I get push notice.
The most important reason for this is that show text message view.

```
func application(_ application: UIApplication, didReceiveRemoteNotification data: [AnyHashable : Any]) {
        // Print notification payload data
        print("My Push: \(data)");
// Run my application with MFMessageComposeViewController.

}
```

My application have a MFMessageComposeViewController so I'd like to call ViewController.swift some of methods.

How can I implement for this?

[Edit]
I mean I want to run my application automatically both screen on and off.
I usually do this job in android with no problem however iOS have a little bit trouble.

Comment: If your app isn't already in the foreground then you will need to display a notification to the user prompting them to open your app.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In iOS, there is no way to launch your app and display its window without explicit interaction from the user.

If your app is in the background, or is terminated when a push notification is received from APNS, iOS will display an alert to the user if one is defined in the push notification payload. The payload is not delivered to terminated or suspended apps unless the user taps on it, indicating that they want to engage with the alert.

An exception is made for VOIP, Apple Watch Complications, or FileProvider apps. These apps can use the [PushKit framework](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/pushkit) to interface with APNS. This framework will launch the app if it is terminated, and deliver the notification payload to the app, even if it is in the background. This however will not display your app's window, only deliver the payload for processing. The user will either need to tap the app's icon on the home screen, or engage with a notification alert presented to make your app visible.

Comment: Thank you very much, This is what I want to know. Perfect :) I understand